# Regular Expression in Java to remove all '\r\n' with trailing space except any ones at end of file

Tags: java, regex

I have situation where I have a string in Java where there are some instances of "\r\n " (notice space at end).  I DO NOT want to replace all line breaks/indents; only the specific occurrences where a \r\n are together and followed by spacing (non-characters).  Furthermore, I do not want to remove any occurrences of this if it is at the end of file (EOF) where there are no characters afterwards.  I want the occurrences (that should be targeted) replaced with a space.

EX) String fileText = "text\r\nMoreText\r\n Hello There!\nHow Are You?\r\n I'm Fine \r\n \r\n "

String regStr = fileText.replaceAll("([^\[a-z][0-9]!?])\r?\n", "$1 ").replaceAll("  +", " "); //This doesn't work and doesn't take into account ignoring any EOF occurrences but it's as far as I've managed to get before hair pulling began.

Expected Outcome) "text\r\nMoreText Hello There!\nHow Are You? I'm Fine \r\n \r\n "

I'm trying to come up with a regular expression where the 2 occurrences of "\r\n " that are before "Hello There!" and "I'm Fine" are removed since they have trailing spaces but the last 2 occurrences are left alone because they are at the end of the file without any other characters afterwards.

Comment: Why does your expected outcome keep the `\r\n` after `text`?

Comment: If the `\r\n` after `text` is a typo in the question, you probably want `s.replaceAll("\r\n(?!(?:\r\n| )*$)", " ")`.

Comment: @ctwheels becuase the \r\n is not followed by a space.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't believe that to be a typo; the "\r\n" in the substring "text\r\nMoreText" does not have a space following it.  I stated in the comments that
1) Only want to replace occurrences of "\r\n " (notice the trailing space) with a space.

2) I do not want to replace any occurrences of this if it is at EOF like the example showed.

If the substring was in fact "text\r\n MoreText", then the expected outcome would be : "text MoreText".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a lookahead based approach:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\r\n\\s+(?!(?:\r\n\\s+)*$)", " ")
```

See the online Java demo.

**Details**

- `\r\n` - CRLF line ending
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespace chars that...
- `(?!(?:\r\n\\s+)*$)` -  ... are not followed with

  - `(?:\r\n\\s+)*` - 0 or more consecutive occurrences of CRLF line endings followed with 1+ whitespace chars followed with...
  - `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks a million, did not even think of the "-" scenario.  Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

This should work perfectly fine, I think for all scenarios. Try this out.

```
String patternToReplace = "(?!(\\\\r\\\\n\\s)*$)(\\\\r\\\\n\\s)";
String s = "text\\r\\nMoreText\\r\\n Hello There!\\nHow Are You?\\r\\n I'm Fine \\r\\n \\r\\n ";
System.out.println(s);
s= s.replaceAll(patternToReplace," ");
System.out.println(s);
```

Output

```
text\r\nMoreText\r\n Hello There!\nHow Are You?\r\n I'm Fine \r\n \r\n 
text\r\nMoreText Hello There!\nHow Are You? I'm Fine \r\n \r\n
```

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew : Request you to please evaluate the above regex/program with your scenario.
Matt: Please test it. Think it will work.

Comment: Above is the look ahead based approach. Test it with some of your data. Let me know if it doesn’t work in any case.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```
String testString = "text\r\nMoreText\r\n Hello There!\nHow Are You?\r\n I'm Fine \r\n \r\n "
String configuredString = testString.replaceAll("(\\r\\n){1}[\\s]+\\b", " ");
```

This gives me the expected output.

```
- The (\\r\\n) signifies I want to look for any "\r\n" within the string.
- The {1} means how often this shall occur.  In this case, once.  The replaceAll() method will handle going through the entire string to find all instances of any more matches.
- [\\s] adds a trailing space so now I'm looking for any occurrence of "\r\n " instead of just "\r\n".
- the + signifies that the character in the square brackets can occur once but not more than once (in this case, a space).
- the \\b causes to ignore all matches right before the beginning of next character.  So this will ignore any EOF occurrences as there are no characters anywhere after the "\r\n " occurrences at the end of file/string.
```

EDIT : While this gave me the output I sought; It has been shown that there are cases (like special characters and punctuation) that it does not account for.  Look at the answer Wiktor Stribiżew made that details the regex expression needed for these cases and how he breaks down what it all means.

Comment: What if `"\r\n "` is followed with punctuation? It won't be removed then though not at the end of the string. Also, no point wrapping `\r\n` with a capturing group and `{1}` may be safely removed. Same as `[` and `]`.

Comment: *`the \\b causes to ignore all matches right before the beginning of next character.  So this will ignore any EOF occurrences as there are no characters anywhere after the "\r\n " occurrences at the end of file/string.`* is wrong since `\b` when placed after a whitespace pattern, requires a word char after these whitespaces.

Comment: Just a wrong explanation then?  Because the output is exactly what I was looking for.  How should I change the explanation then?  Or did I just get lucky with the outcome?

Comment: Your regex is wrong, because you will not replace `"\r\n "` from `"Text\r\n - Hello There"` Have you checked my approach yet?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a completely different approach:

1. Split the String to a List or Array (perhaps by the delimiter `\s*\r\n\s*`)
2. Normalize each List item (e.g. trim, convert multiple line breaks to one, etc.)
3. Join the list again, using a delimiter of your choice

e.g.

```
String repaired = Arrays.stream(text.split("\s*\r\n\s*")
                        .map(String::trim) // possibly more .map() calls
                        .filter(s->!s.isEmpty())
                        .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```